# Form validation autoscroll modification javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a javascript validation of a form. My problem is, that upon submitting the form, the browser jumps automatically to the empty cells. This is not a problem and I like it this way. My problem is that, there is a fixed header displayed on my page, and this header covers up the form-field. Is there any way to get around it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it like this:

**EventListener binding:**

```
  $('input').on('invalid',function() {
    scrollToInvalid();
  });
```

**Function:**

```
function scrollToInvalid() {

  //Height of your nav bar with some offset
  var navHeight = $('nav#main').height() + 20;

  // Offset of the first input element minus your nav height
  var firstInvalidPosTop = $('input:invalid').first().offset().top;
  var newScrollPos       = firstInvalidPosTop - navHeight;

  // return true if the invalid element is already within the window view. 
  // If you return false, the validation will stop.
  if (  newScrollPos > (window.pageYOffset + navHeight) && 
        newScrollPos < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - navHeight)) {
    return true;
  } else {

    // If the first invalid input is not within the current view, scroll to the new position.
    $('html, body').scrollTop(newScrollPos);
  }
};
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you so much! Have a great day!